# Excel VBA DoubleClick

Tags: vba, excel, double-click

I'm working on a work project where I have an excel sheet with values that turn red when they are out of spec. What I'd like to do is be able to double click on a cell and have the sheet in my workbook pop up that has trending data on it. I have already created the sheet with the graph on it. Long story short, I'd like to be able to double click on a specific cell and have it bring up the corresponding sheet.

I have tried this code, and it will not work. Is anyone able to maybe write code from scratch or alter the code so I could use it? The cell I'm trying to click on is N9, and the sheet I want it to open is called "Alpha Final Rinse"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
    Sheets("Alpha Final Rinse").Select
End Sub
```

I'm doing this in Excel 2013. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **only** want N9 to be able to switch focus to another worksheet, isolate **Target** with the [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772.aspx).

In the data worksheet's code sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N9")) Is Nothing Then
        cancel = True
        Worksheets("Alpha Final Rinse").Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that `cancel = True` is necessary to stop the user entering in-cell edit mode (assuming that has been enabled in Options).

Comment: `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` is an **event handler**. If you have crashed or errored out with `Application.EnableEvents = False` then you need to turn event handling back on again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if:

- it is installed in the worksheet code area of your data sheet (the sheet whose cells you are double-clicking)
- macros are enabled
- the file type is **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

Comment: Don't forget to set `Cancel = True` so the user does not enter in-cell edit mode.